# accounting for spaces when grouping numbers with regex

Tags: javascript

I have the function below which decodes each number to its corresponding letter after splitting it by 2 and then returns a decoded string the problem I'm having is accounting for spaces in my regex so that i can make "tens" an array which includes a space as a string or something along those lines.

right now if you take const tens out of the function in isolation it will give you an array of digits grouped by 2 but will leave out the space and so within the function the output of `decodePS` is `'bookbook'` what i need is `'book book'`. i also need the number `42` to return both `i/j` so if it were to be passed `214222` i should get `b(i/j)g` which i believe at this point its does.

```js
const alpha = [
  {letter: "a",number:"11"},
  {letter: "b",number:"21"},
  {letter: "c",number:"31"},
  {letter: "d",number:"41"},
  {letter: "e",number:"51"},
  {letter: "f",number:"12"},
  {letter: "g",number:"22"},
  {letter: "h",number:"32"},
  {letter: "(i/j)",number:"42"},
  {letter: "k",number:"52"},
  {letter: "l",number:"13"},
  {letter: "m",number:"23"},
  {letter: "n",number:"33"},
  {letter: "o",number:"43"},
  {letter: "p",number:"53"},
  {letter: "q",number:"14"},
  {letter: "r",number:"24"},
  {letter: "s",number:"34"},
  {letter: "t",number:"44"},
  {letter: "u",number:"54"},
  {letter: "v",number:"15"},
  {letter: "w",number:"25"},
  {letter: "x",number:"35"},
  {letter: "y",number:"45"},
  {letter: "z",number:"55"}
]; 

function search(arr, x) {

  let i = 0;
  let count = arr.length;
  while (i < count) {
    if (arr[i].number == x) {
      return arr[i].letter;
    }
    if (arr[i].letter == x) {
      return arr[i].number;
    }
    i++;
  }

  return x
}

function decodePS(input) {
  const tens = input.match(/\d{1,2}/g)
  console.log(tens)
  return tens.reduce((acc, num) => acc + search(alpha, num), "")
}

console.log(decodePS("21434352 21434352"))
```

Comment: Why do you have `if (arr[i].number == x) {
      return arr[i].letter;
    }` twice in `search`?

Comment: And why not use the built-in function `arr.find()`?

Comment: my bad they should be opposite each other                                   
       ``` function search(arr, x) {
        let i = 0;
        let count = arr.length;
       while (i < count) {
       if (arr[i].number == x) {
        return arr[i].letter;
       }
      if (arr[i].letter== x) {
      return arr[i].number;
      }
      i++;
     }
      return x
      }```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regexp that matches either two digits or a space:

```
/\d{1,2}| /
```

The `|` separates alternative patterns to match.

You can also simplify the `search()` function by using the built-in `.find()` method.

```js
const alpha = [
  {letter: "a",number:"11"},
  {letter: "b",number:"21"},
  {letter: "c",number:"31"},
  {letter: "d",number:"41"},
  {letter: "e",number:"51"},
  {letter: "f",number:"12"},
  {letter: "g",number:"22"},
  {letter: "h",number:"32"},
  {letter: "(i/j)",number:"42"},
  {letter: "k",number:"52"},
  {letter: "l",number:"13"},
  {letter: "m",number:"23"},
  {letter: "n",number:"33"},
  {letter: "o",number:"43"},
  {letter: "p",number:"53"},
  {letter: "q",number:"14"},
  {letter: "r",number:"24"},
  {letter: "s",number:"34"},
  {letter: "t",number:"44"},
  {letter: "u",number:"54"},
  {letter: "v",number:"15"},
  {letter: "w",number:"25"},
  {letter: "x",number:"35"},
  {letter: "y",number:"45"},
  {letter: "z",number:"55"}
]; 

function search(arr, x) {
  let match = arr.find(el => el.number == x);
  if (match) {
    return match.letter;
  }
  match = arr.find(el => el.letter == x);
  if (match) {
    return match.number;
  }
  return x;
}

function decodePS(input) {
  const tens = input.match(/\d{1,2}| /g)
  console.log(tens)
  return tens.reduce((acc, num) => acc + search(alpha, num), "")
}

console.log(decodePS("21434352 21434352"))
```

Comment: I had the search func extra step matching letter to number so that i could do the reverse in my encode function but regardless what do u mean by alt regex ate you reffering to the ```|```

Comment: Yes, that's what I referred to, I'll clarify.

Comment: okay cool ill see if that works then come back to u. also using find() does simplify things a bit. good idea